# Using linq how to get counts of integer in my list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of numbers in my array. I need to get count of number which are less than 5.
How may i achieve this?

I know using count method, I can do this but while am trying to invoke `c.Count()` there is no method like count is showing is showing. Is there any other method to get count?

```
var num = from c in list 
          where c < 5
          select c;
```

Comment: List of int variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it out this will work as your needs

```
var num = (from c in list 
where c < 5
select c).Count();
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply, using [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) which takes a `Func<T, bool>`:

```
var numberCount = list.Count(n => n < 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = YourList.Where(n => n < 5).Count();
```

Comment: I think you mean `Where`, not `Select`.

Comment: You can even get rid of Where, YourList.Count(n => n < 5) ;)

Answer (score 1):

> .i know using count method i can do this but while am trying to invoke c.Count() there is no method like count is showing is showing

You need to enclose your query with parentheses :

```
var num = (from c in list 
           where c < 5
           select c).Count();
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a bit "vague" to say the least,

maybe this is what you meant:

```
   var num = from c in list 
                where list.Count(x => x == c) < 5
                select c;
```